# Why can’t I install iOS 10.3.3?

Tags: ios, ipad

iPad 4, currently iOS 8.4.1. The software downloaded, but the download was interrupted at one point due to insufficient memory. I then factory reset my iPad and began the download again. When it was finished, I pressed “Install”, and was prompted to enter my passcode. I did, it loaded for a second, then the “Install Now” button return to blue, as if I hadn’t pressed it. I clicked on it a few times; it no longer asked for my passcode, but just loaded for a second, then returned to blue.

I have read online that I can update my iPad with a computer but I don’t have one currently. I have seen I can delete the file in Storage and redownload it, but it doesn’t appear under Settings -> iCloud -> Storage -> Manage Storage, only various apps.

I could factory reset the iPad again, or, does anyone know if there’s somewhere else I could look for the file to delete it, and redownload it?

Comment: Try taking it to an Apple Store. They'll probably install the latest iOS for that iPad.